# GraphQL query in Node.js returns AWS CloudWatch error "Unable to import module 'index'"

Tags: node.js, graphql, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

The below GraphQL request is [based on this tutorial](https://www.voicewithjavascript.com/blog/2016-12-17-making-sense-of-the-scaas-new-flavor-wheel/) and the [Alexa NodeJS HelloWorld boilerplate](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-hello-world). After running the invocation name Alexa returns "There was a problem with the requested skill's response".
The skill is *custom* + *Alexa hosted*.

AWS CloudWatch Log:

```
START RequestId: 1992effc-ec02-42fc-bd5f-22df89b16598 Version: 13
Unable to import module 'index': Error
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:6:27)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
END RequestId: 1992effc-ec02-42fc-bd5f-22df89b16598
```

NodeJS Code:

```
 const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');
    const { GraphQLClient } = require('graphql-request');
    const GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/cixos23120m0n0173veiiwrjr';
    const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient(GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT, { })
    const helloWorldQuery = `
        {
          Movie(title: "Inception") {
            releaseDate
            actors {
              name
            }
          }
        }
      `

    const LaunchRequestHandler = {
      canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
      },
      handle(handlerInput) {
        const speechText = 'Welcome to the Alexa Skills Kit, you can say hello!';

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak(speechText)
          .reprompt(speechText)
          .withSimpleCard('Hello World', speechText)
          .getResponse();
      },
    };

    const HelloWorldIntentHandler = {
     canHandle(handlerInput) {
     return (
          handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest' && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'HelloWorldIntent'
        );
      },
     async handle(handlerInput) {
     const response = await graphQLClient.request(helloWorldQuery);

     const speechText = `Hello World ${response}`;

     return handlerInput.responseBuilder
     .speak(speechText)
     // .withSimpleCard('GraphQL Query', speechText)
          .getResponse();
      },
    };
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: I tried deleting, didn't work. Also I got downvoted anyway...

Comment: Why should you delete it? What's bad with it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what could be the issue, I just performed a test and you can find the results [here](https://github.com/frivas/hello-world-skill-tom)

Just as example, this is what I get back from the query:

2019-06-16T21:48:05.702Z    e45cf19c-daf9-4aa8-90ef-d7e827655d21    INFO    Query Result =
{
    "Movie": {
        "releaseDate": "2010-08-28T20:00:00.000Z",
        "actors": [
            {
                "name": "Leonardo DiCaprio"
            },
            {
                "name": "Ellen Page"
            },
            {
                "name": "Tom Hardy"
            },
            {
                "name": "Joseph Gordon-Levitt"
            },
            {
                "name": "Marion Cotillard"
            }
        ]
    }
}

The example skill just make Alexa say the movie is starred by Leonardo DiCaprio:

const speechText = `The movie Inception is starred by ${response.Movie.actors[0].name}`;

I hope this helps you finding the error.

Feel free to copy the github repository and build up from there.